# Problem with a Curvature Calculation on $S^3\rightarrow S^2$

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-topology, differential-forms, curvature, connections

Sorry this going to be mildly long, I am having trouble obtaining what I think I should when I pull back the curvature form $S^3$ to $S^2$ via a local section, and would like to see if someone can point out a mistake in my reasoning. I also would prefer to avoid the identification of $S^2\cong \mathbb{C}P^1$.

Let $S^3$ be the unit three sphere, and $S^1$ the circle. There exists a free and proper right action on $S^3$ by $S^1$, given by:
$$(z_1,z_2)\cdot e^{i\theta}=(z_1\cdot e^{i\theta},z_2\cdot e^{i\theta})$$
Since the action is free and proper we have that $S^3/S^1\cong S^2$ is a smooth manifold, and that the projection map $\pi:S^3\rightarrow S^2$ is a smooth submersion. By identifying $\mathbb{R}^2\cong \mathbb{C}$, we see that:
$$S^2=\{(w,z)\in \mathbb C\times\mathbb R:|w|^2+z^2=1\}$$
Thus the map:
$$\begin{align}
F:S^3/S^1&\longrightarrow S^2\\
 [z_1,z_2]&\longmapsto \left(2z_1\bar{z}_2, 2|z_1|^2-1\right)
\end{align}$$
is a diffeomorphism as it is a well defined, smooth bijection, with an invertible differential map at each point. So the projection map $\pi:S^3\rightarrow S^2$ should be be given by:
$$\pi((z_1,z_2))=(2z_1\bar{z}_2,2|z_1|^2-1)$$
as it is smooth, surjective, and satisfies $\pi((z_1,z_2)\cdot e^{i\theta})=\pi((z_1,z_2))$. I believe I can then write down a local section as $s:U=S^2\smallsetminus\{(0,1)\}\rightarrow S^3$ by:
$$\begin{align}
 s(w,z)=\left(i\sqrt{\frac{1}{2}(1-z)}, \frac{1}{2}\frac{i\bar w}{\sqrt{\frac{1}{2}(1-z)}}\right)
\end{align}$$
Which indeed takes image in $S^3$:
$$\begin{align}
\frac{1}{2}(1-z)+\frac{1}{2}\frac{|w|^2}{(1-z)}=&\frac{1}{2}(1-z)+\frac{1}{2}\frac{1-z^2}{(1-z)}\\
=&\frac{1}{2}(1-z)+\frac{1}{2}(1+z)\\
=&1
\end{align}$$
Furthermore:
$$\begin{align}
\pi\circ s(w,z)=&\left(2i\sqrt{\frac{1}{2}(1-z)}\cdot \frac{1}{2}\frac{-iw}{\sqrt{\frac{1}{2}(1-z)}}, \frac{|w|^2}{(1-z)}-1\right)\\
=&\left(w, \frac{1-z^2}{(1-z)}-1\right)\\
=&\left(w,1+z-1\right)\\
=&(w,z)
\end{align}$$
so $\pi\circ s=\text{Id}_U$ and is thus a smooth section of $\pi$.

Finally, we have a connection one form $A$ on $S^3$ given by:
$$A=(\bar{z}_1dz_1-z_1d\bar{z}_1+\bar{z}_2dz_2-z_2d\bar{z}_2)$$
Since $S^1$ is abelian, it follows that the curvature form:
$$\begin{align}
F^A=&dA+\frac{1}{2}[A,A]\\
   =&dA\\
   =&-(dz_1\wedge d\bar{z}_1+dz_1\wedge d\bar{z}_2)
\end{align}$$

I want to pull this back $F^A$ back to $U$ by $s$, and this form on $U$ should extend to a globally defined two form on $S^2$ as $S^1$ is abelian. I have reason to believe that I should get the standard volume form of $S^2$ which is given by:
$$
\omega=xdy\wedge dz+ydz\wedge dx+zdx\wedge dy
$$
One can check with the angle parameterization of $S^2$:
$$\phi^{-1}(\theta,\phi)=(\sin\theta\cos\phi,\sin\theta\sin\phi,\cos\theta)$$
that:
$$(\phi^{-1})^*\omega=\sin\theta d\theta\wedge d\phi$$
so this is indeed the volume form on $S^2$.

Proceeding, I calculate:
$$\begin{align}
s^*(dz_1)=&d(z_1\circ s)\\
=&\frac{-idz}{2\sqrt{2}\sqrt{1-z}}
\end{align}$$
while:
$$d(\bar{z}_1\circ s)=\frac{idz}{2\sqrt{2}\sqrt{1-z}}$$
hence:
$$s^*(dz_1\wedge d\bar{z}_1)=d(z_1\circ s)\wedge d(\bar{z}_1\circ s)=0$$
Furthermore:
$$\begin{align}
d(z_2\circ s)=\frac{i\bar{w}dz}{2\sqrt{2}(1-z)^{3/2}}+\frac{id\bar{w}}{\sqrt{2}\sqrt{1-z}}
\end{align}$$
and:
$$\begin{align}
d(\bar{z}_2\circ s)=\frac{-i{w}dz}{2\sqrt{2}(1-z)^{3/2}}+\frac{-id{w}}{\sqrt{2}\sqrt{1-z}}
\end{align}$$
so:
$$s^*(dz_2\wedge d\bar{z}_2)=\frac{\bar w}{4(1-z)^2}dz\wedge dw +\frac{w}{4(1-z)^2}
        d\bar w\wedge dy +\frac{1}{2(1-z)}d\bar{w}\wedge dw$$

Letting $w=x+iy$ we obtain that:
$$s^*(dz_2\wedge d\bar{z}_2)=\frac{-ix}{2(1-z)^2}dy\wedge dz+\frac{-iy}{2(1-z)^2}dz \wedge dx+\frac{-i}{(1-z)}dy\wedge dx$$
Hence:
$$s^*F^A=\frac{ix}{2(1-z)^2}dy\wedge dz+\frac{iy}{2(1-z)^2}dz \wedge dx+\frac{i}{(1-z)}dy\wedge dx$$
Which to me does not at all seem like it is equal to $\omega$. I know that it should be some scalar times $\omega$ since the book I'm using shows that the volume form in a chart on $S^2$ gives rise to the curvature form. I could do something similar, but I wanted to start with the curvature form and go backwards since the other way seems contrived.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Edit to Add Integral:

We pull $s^*F$ back by the angle parameterization of $S^2$:
$$\phi^{-1}(\theta,\phi)=(\sin\theta\cos\phi,\sin\theta\sin\phi,
\cos\theta)$$
which leaves out a set of measure zero in $S^2$, hence:

$$\int_{S^2}s^*F=\int_0^\pi\int_{0}^{2\pi}\phi^{-1*}(s^*F)$$

We see that:
$$
\begin{align}
\phi^{-1*}(s^*F)=\frac{i\sin\theta}{1-\cos\theta}d\theta\wedge d\phi
\end{align}
$$

So:
$$
\begin{align}
\int_{S^2}s^*F=&2\pi \int_0^\pi\frac{\sin\theta}{1-\cos\theta}\\
\end{align}
$$
which clearly doesn't converge so something is off here...

Edit to Add:

Completely messed up the calculation of the pull back. It ends ups being

$$\phi^{-1*}(s^*F)=\frac{i}{2}\sin\theta d\theta\wedge d\phi$$

So that makes much more sense.

Comment: There’s no reason (given that you’re purposely ignoring the obvious underlying complex geometry) that the pullback should be $\omega$. It  should just be cohomologous. What’s the integral of your form?

Comment: Remember that you need a factor of $i/2\pi$ as well.

Comment: If I did not purposely ignore the complex structure would it work out how I envisioned? If so how? Also editing to add the integral

Comment: @TedShifrin I made an error in my problem statement, I expect to get a purely imaginary scalar multiple of the volume form.

Comment: If you work with the natural section of $S^3 \to \Bbb CP^1 = \Bbb C\cup\{\infty\}$, you have $\sigma(z) = (1,z)/\sqrt{1+|z|^2}$, and the pullback will be $dz\wedge d\bar z/(1+|z|^2)^2$, which is what you want.

Comment: But thats just the pull back $\omega$ by the inverse of stereographic projection $\phi^{-1}:\mathbb C\rightarrow S^2-(0,0,1)$ isn't it?

Comment: Yup. So my section works perfectly :)

Comment: I see, but I dont understand why section shouldn't give me that same form if I pull back the form by the aforementioned chart. Also for some reason my integral doesnt converge so something must be wrong there two.

Comment: Yes, you’re right that the pullbacks of the *curvature* form by different sections should actually be equal.

Comment: @TedShifrin So are there multiple two forms on $\mathbb R^3$ that when pulled back to a coordinate chart for $S^2$ yield the volume form in coordinates? Because it feels like that what just happened here. The $s^*F$ form I obtained was really a form living in $\mathbb R^3$, much like $\omega$, but when I pull it back with $\phi^{-1}$ I see that it is the same form as $\phi^{-1*}\omega$.